# how to authenticate in HTTPS by NetHTTPClient

Tags: c++, authentication, https

Hello

I must stress that I dont want use curl, and I must use only Embarcadero compiler. (C++Builder and Delphi)

I want send a request to a server which need authentication.

The complete command by API documentation is:

`curl -X POST "https://api.demo.website.com/api/2/something" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "symbol=BTC&side=buy&type=limit&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.1&price=4000"`

Their Authentication style they provide is:

`curl -u "publicKey:secretKey" https://api.demo.website.com/api/2/something`
Their suggested code is: (which is not C++) :-))

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.auth = ("publicKey", "secretKey")
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const credentials = Buffer.from('publicKey' + ':' + 'secretKey').toString('base64');
fetch('https://api.demo.website.com/api/2/something', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials
    }
});
```

My Code is:

```
TCredentialsStorage::TCredential *MyCredential = new TCredentialsStorage::TCredential(
        TAuthTargetType::Server, "", "",
        UserNameEdit->Text, PasswordEdit->Text);
NetHTTPClient1->CredentialsStorage->AddCredential(*MyCredential);
StatMemo->Lines->Add(IntToStr(NetHTTPClient1->CredentialsStorage->Credentials.RefCount));

TMemoryStream *Response=new TMemoryStream;
TMemoryStream *bbkTMS  =new TMemoryStream;
TNameValueArray nva;
NetHTTPRequest1->Post(URLEdit->Text, bbkTMS, Response, nva);
StatMemo->Lines->LoadFromStream(bbkTMS);
Memo1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Response);
```

The code is compiling but ot working... :-|
It said:
`{"error":{"code":1004,"message":"Unsupported authorization method"}}`

Any suggestion for me?

Comment: Temporary change the URL to a non-encrypted to your own web server, run it under strace and see what goes over the wire, then figure out what to do once you see what comes out on the socket. Basic debugging.

Comment: Sure I did everything came into my mind to fix this prob, but I got desperate, so I came her to ask for help.

Comment: So? What did your trace show, what goes over the socket? This shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to set up, and test.

Answer (score 0):

I find it out :-)

As I am using RAD Tool (Embarcadero) So I can use its VCL/FMX component:

THTTPBasicAuthenticator

Done!

But instead NetHTTP component group I start using RESTClient component group, much more better.